# Trying to get the difference between two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. `$array_advise` and `$array_oab`, respectively.

> Array ( [0] => Array ([oab] => 226015 ) ... )
>
> Array(  [0] => Array([oab]=> 289240 )... )

The first one is the bigger array with the complete data. The second one is smaller. What I want is what is in `$array_oab` and is not in `the $array_advise`.

I tried with `array_diff()`, but it returns an empty array. What I'm doing wrong ?

**Edit**

> ```
>   foreach ($lista_advise as $value_advise) {
>     $array_advise[] = array("oab"=>trim($value_advise["OABNumero"]));
>     $array_advise_nome[] = array("vinculo"=>$value_advise["nomeVinculo"]);
>    // print_r($array_advise_nome);
>   }              
>     foreach ($corporativos->lista as $value){     
>       $input = $value["info_adicionais"];
>       $input = utf8_decode($input);
>       $input = trim($input);
>       $data = json_decode($input,true);          
>       if ($data["andamentos"] != NULL) {
>         $advogados = explode(";",$data["andamentos"]);
>         foreach ($advogados as $advogado) {
>           $dados = explode(",",$advogado);
>           $oab = explode("/",$dados[1]);
>           //  print_r(strtoupper(removerAcento($array_adv[0]["nome"])));  
>           $array_adv[] = array("cliente" => $value["nome"], "clienteid" => $value["clienteId"] ,"nome"=>$dados[0], "oab"=>$oab[0], "estados"=>$oab[1]);  
>           $array_oab[] = array("oab" => trim($oab[0]));
>         }
>       }
>     }      
>     print_r(array_diff($array_oab, $array_advise));
> ```

I edited with my code, the output is a empty array.

Comment: Can you post your complete tried code ? And if possible eg of an expected output.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can't use array_diff() with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: What you are doing wrong? In order for us to answer that you should specify what you are actually doing.

Comment: There's no day in stackoverflow without the typical php question "How do I compare those two arrays?" or "How do I do that with 2D-Arrays in PHP?" (Like accessing values in it)

Comment: Why is it so hard to print data you're working with when asking questions, what's `$lista_advise`, `$corporativos->lista` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_diff()` works with single-dimension arrays only. You have to use [`array_udiff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php).
Something like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
return $a['oab'] == $b['oab']? 0 : 1;
}

array_udiff($array_oab, $array_advise, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

### [array_diff](http://pk1.php.net/array_diff)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```